# Tkinter: Solving a math problem using percentages from 2 entry boxes

Tags: python, tkinter, math

I feel like I'm not quite getting the grasp on how to write out Math using Python so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. Here's what I'm trying to do:

X and Y have its own entry box. You type in the two numbers and it's suppose to give you the percentage between the two. I.e if X = 10 and Y = 9, it's a 10% difference but with a 77% adjustment. Ignore the point though.

X - Y / X * .77

So far I got:

Note: I had to censor a lot of sensitive labels so please ignore the weird titles for things.

EDIT UPDATED WITH SUGGESTED CODE

```
def ---():
    Z = StringVar()
    Z.set("-")

    def roto_calc():
        x = (float(first_strip.get())
        y = (float(second_strip.get())
        Z.set = ((x - y)/ x * .77)
        result.config(text=f"{Z}")

     yyy = Toplevel(root)
     yyy.title("111")
     yyy.geometry("400x300")

     uuu_frame = LabelFrame(yyy, text=".", height=400)
     uuu_frame.grid(padx=20)

     first_slice = Entry(uuu_frame, font=("Helvetica", 12))
     first_slice.grid(padx=20)

     second_slice = Entry(uuu_frame, font=("Helvetica", 12))
     second_slice.grid(padx=20)

     result = Label(yyy, textvariable=Z)

     submit = Button(yyy, text="Calculate", command=roto_calc)
     submit.grid(padx=20)
```

Comment: You are trying to create a Label with the calculation results, long before any calculation has been performed.  Creating the Label up front is reasonable, but you need to actually set its text from within the `xxx()` function.  Also note that `.get()` on your Entries will return strings, you need to convert those strings to numbers before any calculation can be performed with them.

Comment: Can I get an example of what that might look like?

Comment: In the function `xxx` your variables are in different cases, when you declare them they are lower case, but when you calculate, they are upper case.

Comment: suggested code is fine once you get suggestions but you should also provide a [mre], also your code is not calling the `roto_calc()` so it won't set the textvariable

Comment: Well it is... in the original version of the code I censored roto_calc into xxx but in my edit, I let it slip that its called roto_calc... so it stayed. My bad. I could edit it to be more clear though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are setting the `text` attribute of the `result` label without ever defining Z. To include variables in Labels you should create a `StringVar()` and then you can use `.set` to set the value.

Secondly, `.get()` returns a string, and you need to convert to `int` or `float` to be able to do calculations.

Thirdly, in the function `xxx` you were using a mix of cases, when you declared the variables as lower case, but then you were using upper case when doing calculations.

```py
def ---():

    Z = StringVar()
    Z.set("-")

    def xxx():
        x = float(first_slice.get())
        y = float(second_slice.get())
        Z.set(x - y / x * 77)

     yyy = Toplevel(root)
     yyy.title("111")
     yyy.geometry("400x300")

     uuu_frame = LabelFrame(yyy, text=".", height=400)
     uuu_frame.grid(padx=20)

     first_slice = Entry(uuu_frame, font=("Helvetica", 12))
     first_slice.grid(padx=20)

     second_slice = Entry(uuu_frame, font=("Helvetica", 12))
     second_slice.grid(padx=20)

     result = Label(yyy, textvariable=Z)
     result.grid(padx=20)

     submit = Button(yyy, text="Calculate", command=xxx)
     submit.grid(padx=20)
```

Comment: Little sidenote I wanted to ask... it seems like the labelframe, the height=400 doesnt wanna work and no matter what adjustment I make to it, it only will size itself to whats inside the labelframe. Do you know why that would be?

Comment: Sorry, accidently tried to edit your code when I meant to do mine above. Ignore that. :(

Comment: Getting a PY_VAR0 return with this.

Comment: Yes, my bad updating answer

Comment: Also not sure about the height problem

Comment: Now it's just resulting nothing. No error no anything. The "-" just stays a dash....

Comment: @Dexsana the current code has to work once you press "Submit", also the frame by default shrinks to fit its elements, to disable this behaviour use `.grid_propagate(False)` (if using `.grid()`) reference: https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/grid-methods.html

Comment: Figured it out. It was the one minor difference between you and Sujay's that I didnt even notice until someone else pointed it out.

Sujay had Z = when its suppose to be Z.set. I've been doing Z= this entire time.

Appreciate all your guys help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the strings to an integer, then configure the result to the text of the `Label`. Also, `result` Label won't appear any where because you haven't given it a position yet. Also, `x,y` are different from `X,Y`. Python is case sensitive.

Also, `.get()` methods return strings. You need to convert that to a floating point, (not integer because it won't accept decimals).

```
def xxx():
    x = float(first_slice.get())
    y = float(second_slice.get())
    Z = ((x - y)/ x * 100)
    result.config(text=f"{Z}")
```

Comment: @LegacyCoding good catch! Updated the answer

Comment: I'm getting a PY_VAR0 return with yours.

Comment: Between you and Legacy Coding, I'm past the PY_VAR0 and instead now I'm just not getting a result at all. Just no change at all. Not even sure what to go on.

And this is using both your codes.

Comment: @Dexsana try moving the function out of the current one

Comment: You mean unindent the roto_calc so it matches with the first? If so, just errors out.

Comment: @Sujay Why not `result.config(text=Z)` instead of `result.config(text=f"{Z}")`?

Comment: @TheLizzard using the method in the answer ensures that the value is a string and not any other type of data!

Comment: @LegacyCoding `tkinter` doesn't mind `int`s/`float`s. It automatically converts them to strings.

Comment: @TheLizzard yes but what about lists and other data types, its not 100% necessary in this scenario but is good practice for when you do get other data types

Comment: @LegacyCoding It's more about preferences. Also I would advice to never pass in a `tuple`/`list`/`dict` inside a `tkinter.Label` for the `text` parameter. First you should convert those data types to strings.